# Beginner WF4 question - When is WF4 useful, really?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

If I want to use a traditional approval type workflow in a regular asp.net system, for example
an order that needs an approval before order is placed. Rather than having the traditional
enum for OrderStatus, can I benefit from using microsoft WF4 (Workflow version 4) for this
or will I just generate more complexity and more code for no added benefit?

Comment: In retrospective, after utilizing EF4 we found it is working nicely for handling these long running flows, or for alot of the traditional handling that was previously handled by Status flags etc in code and in database.

One issue is that you get more complex deployment with the workflows and their config files, and you also get a challenge in "finding the data". We had to resort to mirroring out status changes from the workflow into the database in order to expose the information to the application via the Entity framework 4 + MVC application that we're building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you have a long running operation like this WF4 is a good possibility. The fact that the graphical designer allows you to show the actual running process, not a Visio copy of it, is also a huge benefit.

There is however a learning curve to WF4 and there are times you have to do things the WF4 way instead of the C#/VB way you did before. That said there is certainly a benefit, thinks like an approval request not being handled in, lets say, 14 days is very easy to do in WF4.